# QuerySnapshot was optimized out firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have the below code:

```
try {
    emit(Response.Loading)
    val tests = test.get().await()
    for (testing in tests.documents) {
```

I'm trying to fetch a bunch of documents from my test collections in `Cloud Firestore`. now, the test collections looks like so for example:

```
document 1 -> test1
document 2 -> test2
document 3 -> test3
```

Now, I have multiple users that I'm testing my app with. user A, `val tests = test.get().await().documents` returns to me all the documents above. user B, however, I get a msg in my android studio console saying that when it reaches this `for (testing in tests.documents)`, the line above it `val tests = test.get().await()` it says that `tests was optimized out`. not sure what that means. and when looking at my app, user B only gets document 1, it doesn't get any of the other documents. Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known bug relating to debugging coroutines (and has nothing to do with the Firebase SDKs specifically).  You can read a lot about it here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48678

And it looks like also it's scheduled to be fixed in Kotlin 1.8.

Comment: I see, but the issue is that user B doesn't get all the data from the database for some reason while user A does. is that also related to the issue u mentioned? wasn't able to tell by reading through that link

Comment: `and when looking at my app, user B only gets document 1, it doesn't get any of the other documents. Any insight?`